# jQuery works in IE 11, Chrome, Firefox but not in Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm building a website which loads in content from a database, so as a result has dynamic elements on the webpage. I use a PHP foreach to generate the jQuery required to allow the navbar to move and pop out based on the content.

I've tested it in IE 11, Chrome, Firefox and Edge and the only one that has an issue is Edge. It gives me 0 jQuery console errors, and it appears as though the jQuery isn't being run. However, it is definitely loaded.

I've tried changing the position of the script tags, wrapping all of the functions in $(document).ready and no luck on any of them. I've also tried changing jQuery versions (my original was 3.3.1) but that didn't do anything either.

```
$('#tri2').click(function() {

                //Gets the window height
                var height = $(window).height();
                //Gets the footer height
                var footerHeight = $(".footer").height();
                //Subtracts the footer height from the height
                height -= footerHeight;
                //Gets width of the sidenav we wish to open
                var sideNavWidth = $("#nav2").width();
                //Checks the sidenav isn't already open, if it isn't it opens
                if (sideNavWidth === 0) {
                    $("#nav2").toggle();
                    $("#nav2").css("minHeight", height + "px");
                    document.getElementById("nav2").style.width = "250px";
                    document.getElementById("nav2").style.marginLeft = "250px";
                    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";

                    //Get width of the window
                    var width = $(window).width();
                    //Get width of the menu bar
                    var menuWidth = $(".menu-container").width();
                    //Subtracts the menu width from the window width
                    width -= menuWidth;
                    //Adds 15px to the width
                    width += 15;
                    //Subtracts the width of the sidenav from the window width
                    width -= 250;
                    //Sets the minwidth of the conetnt container to the width its allowed
                    $(".content-container").css("minWidth", width + "px");
                    //Sets the maxwidth of the conetnt container to the width its allowed
                    width -= 140;
                    $(".actual-content-container").css("maxWidth", width + "px");

                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case21").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case21").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case21").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case21").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case21").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case21").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case21").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay21").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay21").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case22").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case22").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case22").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case22").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case22").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case22").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case22").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay22").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay22").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case23").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case23").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case23").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case23").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case23").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case23").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case23").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay23").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay23").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case24").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case24").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case24").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case24").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case24").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case24").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case24").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay24").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay24").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case25").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case25").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case25").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case25").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case25").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case25").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case25").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay25").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay25").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case36").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case36").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case36").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case36").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case36").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case36").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case36").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay36").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay36").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case37").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case37").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case37").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case37").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case37").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case37").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case37").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay37").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay37").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case38").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case38").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case38").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case38").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case38").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case38").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case38").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay38").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay38").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case39").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case39").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case39").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case39").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case39").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case39").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case39").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay39").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay39").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case310").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case310").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case310").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case310").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case310").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case310").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case310").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay310").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay310").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case311").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case311").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case311").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case311").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case311").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case311").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case311").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay311").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay311").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case312").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case312").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case312").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case312").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case312").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case312").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case312").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay312").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay312").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case313").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case313").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case313").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case313").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case313").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case313").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case313").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay313").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay313").style.width = "0px";


                    }


                    var sideNavWidth = $("#case314").width();

                    if (sideNavWidth !== 0) {
                        $("#case314").fadeToggle();
                        document.getElementById("case314").style.width = "250px";
                        document.getElementById("case314").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                        document.getElementById("case314").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                        document.getElementById("case314").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                        document.getElementById("case314").style.width = "0px";
                        $("#overlay314").fadeOut("fast");
                        document.getElementById("overlay314").style.width = "0px";

                        /
                    }

                                    }






                setTimeout(
                    function() {

                                                //Checks that if another sidenav is open
                        var sideNavWidth = $("#nav3").width();
                        //If it is hide it
                        if (sideNavWidth > 0) {

                            $("#nav3").fadeToggle();
                            document.getElementById("nav3").style.width = "250px";
                            document.getElementById("nav3").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                            document.getElementById("nav3").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                            document.getElementById("nav3").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                            document.getElementById("nav3").style.width = "0px";

                        }

                                                //Checks that if another sidenav is open
                        var sideNavWidth = $("#nav7").width();
                        //If it is hide it
                        if (sideNavWidth > 0) {

                            $("#nav7").fadeToggle();
                            document.getElementById("nav7").style.width = "250px";
                            document.getElementById("nav7").style.marginLeft = "150px";
                            document.getElementById("nav7").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                            document.getElementById("nav7").style.marginLeft = "0px";
                            document.getElementById("nav7").style.width = "0px";

                        }


                    }, 400);

            });
```

That should work out the screen size and should push the sidenav to the right and allow a second sidenav to appear alongside it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of MS Edge you are using to make a test? Did you try to verify that JQuery code get called and run? If not, than try to use console.log to print the message in console to verify that code is executing. If possible for you than you can try to post an example which can produce the issue with Edge may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Also, as this is a JS issue, please post the actual output without the PHP logic.

Comment: @VLAZ I've used the debugging window within Edge and it has 0 warnings or errors, same with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I'm running Edge 42.17134.1.0, there is other bits of jQuery that get called and run fine, as for that code block in particular it has printed to console in Edge.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've updated the code above to include the raw JS

Comment: I mean post a code sample which can produce the issue on our end. We don't know your HTML and other code. So we are not able to produce the issue with your above JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by downgrading from jQuery 3.3.1 to 3.1.1,